# How to use a proxy server with HTMLUnit?

Tags: java, proxy, htmlunit

I'm using HTMLUnit and would like to use a proxy server. I don't really know much about this, but I was under the impression that one of the servers listed at http://proxylist.hidemyass.com/ would work.

This is my code:

```
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_31, "61.234.249.126", 8118);

        HtmlPage page       = webClient.getPage("http://www.google.com");
        webClient.close();

        System.out.println(page.asText());
    }

}
```

That I.P and port were randomly picked from such list - as I did with several others.

But it just ends up saying that it timed out. I imagine that not all proxy servers will work, but I've done this with more than a dozen addresses, so I'm starting to suspect it is a problem with my code and not the servers themselves.

Am I doing this right?

Comment: At least s of now, WebClient takes parameters (String host, Int port). There is also the option to set the proxy in the command line and to use @Ahmed Ashour's answer

Answer (score 8):

There is a configuration of WebClient.getOption() to [specify the proxy configuration](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/WebClientOptions.html#setProxyConfig(com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ProxyConfig)).

```
ProxyConfig proxyConfig = new ProxyConfig("myhost", myport);
webClient.getOptions().setProxyConfig(proxyConfig);
```

Comment: This answer could be improved if it made an effort to explain what the user is doing wrong so that hopefully they can avoid making a similar mistake in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting up the proxy settings using the System.setProperty() call or using command line option.

```
$ java -Dhttp.proxyHost=x.y.z.a -Dhttp.proxyPort=pppp
-Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=”localhost|host.example.com” your_main_class
```

or use, `System.setProperty(String, String)` call to set appropriate value

Answer (score 0):

Your code has not any problem, the connection timeout depends on the quality of the proxy server, try setting a (large) timeout and most of them will work

```
webClient.getOptions().setTimeout(15000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not every proxy you find is fast enough or gives the responses you would expect. Here is a framework that allows you to use HtmlUnit over a list of proxies while verifying that the proxies used are actually working and the results are what you actually expected: https://github.com/subes/invesdwin-webproxy